# How to prove 2 random variables are independent in probability?

Tags: probability

The joint probability $p(w,x,y,z)$ can be factorized as $$p(w,x,y,z)=p(w)p(z|y)p(y|x,w)p(x)$$, then is $x$ independent of $w$? How to prove?

This is a homework problem, but I can't seem to prove it. AFAIK, it can be factorized as this $$p(w,x,y,z)=p(w|x,y,z)p(x|y,z)p(y|z)p(z)$$, and the order of these variables doesn't matter, but how could I relate this one to the above? OK, I tried another way around, assume $x$ is indeed independent of $w$, then according the original factorization, I have \begin{align*}p(w,x,y,z)&=p(z|y)p(y|x,w)p(w)p(x)\\ &=p(z|y)p(y|x,w)p(w,x)\\ &=p(z|y)p(w,x,y)\end{align*}, right? And $$p(w,x,y,z)=p(z|w,x,y)p(w,x,y)$$, which means $$p(z|y)=p(z|w,x,y)$$? OH..., I'm stuck

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Comment: @Did, right away.

Comment: @Did, I include what I tried, ;-)

Comment: Hint: deduce $p(w,x)$ from $p(w,x,y,z)$.

Comment: @Did, do you mean marginalization?

Comment: @Did, I failed, and honestly I still stuck with $p(wx)=\frac{p(x)p(w)p(z|y)}{p(z|w,x,y)}$, which means I still have to prove $p(z|y)=p(z|w,x,y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$
p(w,x)=\sum_{y,z}p(w,x,y,z)=p(w)p(x)\sum_yp(y\mid w,x)\sum_zp(z\mid y)=\underline{\qquad}
$$

Comment: Conditional probability sums to one, so $\sum_yp(y|w,x)\sum_zp(z|y)=1$. Stupid me, thank you so much.